# A summation including binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, analytic-combinatorics

I'm trying to solve a problem. It led to such a summation :

$$f(n)=\sum_{i\, =\, \left\lceil\, n/2 \,\right\rceil}^{\infty}
{\binom{i + k}{i}\binom{2i}{n}{(-a)}^i}$$

Where $k$ is a nonnegative integer, $a$ is a non-negative real number and both are given.

How can I find it as a closed form function of $n$?

Comment: I would start to simplify the binomials.

Comment: @Daniel How? You mean by writing the factorial form? I have tried it and I think it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that it coud simplify since it is almost the definition of the gaussian hypergeometric function.

If $n=2m$, you would get
$$(-a)^m \binom{k+m}{m} \, _2F_1\left(m+\frac{1}{2},k+m+1;\frac{1}{2};-a\right)$$

Comment: What about odd numbers of $n$? And is there an appropriate way to calculate the hypergeometric function numerically?

Comment: Can you explain why it is converted to this form?